# How to grant and revoke privilege? After Grant select on all tables I can't revoke select from specific user

Tags: sql, postgresql

First of all I did this

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user1, user2
```

Then I need to revoke select from user1 on field salary in table seller

```
REVOKE SELECT(salary) ON seller FROM user1
```

However when I sign in as user1 I still can view while table seller and salary

What is correct way to allow users to select on all tables and then remove this privilege for specific column for one user?

Answer (score 1):

From [grant-documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-grant.html)

> Granting the privilege at the table level and then revoking it for one column will not do what one might wish: the table-level grant is unaffected by a column-level operation.

You need to:

```
REVOKE SELECT ON seller FROM user1;
```

Then:

```
GRANT SELECT (col1,col2....) ON seller TO user1;
```